# RewriteMap dbm .dir .pag

Tags: apache-2.4, centos7, mod-rewrite

I have been working with RewriteMap dbm, I was able to the text version working however cannot figure out how or why I am getting the error described below.

The Virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/sites/me
ServerName domain.com
RewriteEngine On
RewriteMap examplemap "dbm:/etc/httpd/conf/redirects.db"
RewriteRule (.*) ${examplemap:$1}
</VirtualHost>
```

When I try to restart httpd it throws an error:

```
[root@mail me]# httpd -t
AH00526: Syntax error on line 367 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:
RewriteMap: file for map examplemap not found:/etc/httpd/conf/redirects.dbm.dir
```

Where is the .dir coming from?

I create a httxt2dbm file redirects.db.dir and that made the error go away.

Couple problems, if I edit line:

```
RewriteMap examplemap "dbm:/etc/httpd/conf/redirects.db"
```

To:

```
RewriteMap examplemap "dbm:/etc/httpd/conf/redirects.db.dir"
```

I get:

```
RewriteMap: file for map examplemap not found:/etc/httpd/conf/redirects.dbm.dir.dir
```

Second problem:

```
[root@mail me]# tail -f /var/log/httpd/error_log
[Wed Sep 19 20:32:42.282075 2018] [rewrite:error] [pid 4136] (2)No such file or directory: [client 50.76.6.29:56744] AH00663: mod_rewrite: can't access DBM RewriteMap file /etc/httpd/conf/redirects.db.pag
```

Where is the pag file coming from?

How do I make this happy and work?

Comment: When you created the original `redirects.db` file, what syntax did you use for the `httxt2dbm` command? At that time was only one file generated, ie. `redirects.db`?

Comment: Yes only one file was created: httxt2dbm -f db -i /etc/httpd/conf/redirects.txt -o /etc/httpd/conf/redirects.db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Yes only one file was created:
>
> ```
> httxt2dbm -f db -i /etc/httpd/conf/redirects.txt -o /etc/httpd/conf/redirects.db
> ```

If you are specifying `db` (ie. Berkeley DB) as the DBM type (`-f DBM_TYPE` argument) when creating the file then you should probably be including this dbm type in the `RewriteMap` directive as well. `.dir` and `.pag` are not Berkeley DB files, so I suspect Apache is using another default (perhaps `SDBM`?) for your rewrite map.

For example:

```
RewriteMap examplemap "dbm=db:/etc/httpd/conf/redirects.db"
```

Alternatively, remove the `-f db` argument when creating your data file (using `httxt2dbm`) so Apache uses its *default*. (Unless you specifically want Berkeley DB files.)